# "No child processes" error thrown by OCaml Sys.command function

Tags: python, c, linux, ocaml, frama-c

I am trying to use Frama-c via python application. This python application sets some env variables and system path. From this application, I am calling Frama-c as a python process as following:

```
cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/frama-c', '-wp', '-wp-print', '-wp-out', '/home/user/temp','/home/user/project/test.c']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

When this code is executed from Python application I am getting following error:

```
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] warning: your preprocessor is not known to handle option ` -nostdinc'. If pre-processing fails because of it, please add -no-cpp-gnu-like option to Frama-C's command-line. If you do not want to see this warning again, use explicitely -cpp-gnu-like option.
[kernel] warning: your preprocessor is not known to handle option `-dD'. If pre-processing fails because of it, please add -no-cpp-gnu-like option to Frama-C's command-line. If you do not want to see this warning again, use explicitely -cpp-gnu-like option.
[kernel] Parsing 2675891095.c (with preprocessing)
[kernel] System error: /usr/bin/gcc -c -C -E -I.  -dD -nostdinc -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc -o '/tmp/2675891095.cc8bf16.i' '/home/user/project/test.c': No child processes
```

I am finding it hard to debug what is causing the error:

> **System error: /usr/bin/gcc -c -C -E -I.  -dD -nostdinc -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc -o '/tmp/2675891095.cc8bf16.i' '/home/user/project/test.c': No child
>   processes**

Is there a way to generate more error log from Frama-c that might help me figure out the issue?

**Note that** this error only occur when I start the process(to execute Frama-c) from my application, and not if I start it from a python console. And it happens only on **Linux machine** and not on Windows machine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

**Update :** 
I realized that by using -kernel-debug flag I can obtain stack trace. So I tried the option and get the following information:

> Fatal error: exception Sys_error("gcc -E -C -I.  -dD -D__FRAMAC__ 
>   -nostdinc -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc -o '/tmp/2884428408.c2da79b.i'
>   '/home/usr/project/test.c': No
>   child processes")
>
> Raised by primitive operation at file
>   "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 472, characters 9-32
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 517,
>   characters 14-26
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 703,
>   characters 46-59
>
> Called from file "list.ml", line 84, characters 24-34
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 703,
>   characters 17-76
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 1587,
>   characters 24-47
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 1667,
>   characters 4-27
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_data/ast.ml", line 108,
>   characters 2-28
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/ast_data/ast.ml", line 116,
>   characters 53-71
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_internals/runtime/boot.ml", line 29,
>   characters 6-20
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml",
>   line 787, characters 2-9
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml",
>   line 817, characters 18-64
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml",
>   line 228, characters 4-8
>
> Re-raised at file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml",
>   line 244, characters 12-15
>
> Called from file "src/kernel_internals/runtime/boot.ml", line 72,
>   characters 2-127

And I looked at the file `"src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 472` and the code executed is `Sys.command cpp_command`.

I am not sure why "No Child Processes" error is thrown when trying to execute execute gcc.

**Update:** I have Ocaml version: 4.02.3, Python version: 2.7.8 and Frama-C version: Silicon-20161101

Comment: It might help to know what system you're running on: Linux, Windows, macOS?

Comment: It is happening only on Linux machine and not on the Windows machine.

Comment: Could you also specify the versions of OCaml and Python you're using? There are some related issues (such as [this one](https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5256)) that only apply to specific versions of Python and/or OCaml.

Comment: I have Ocaml version: 4.02.3, Python version: 2.7.8 and Frama-C version:  Silicon-20161101

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to reproduce it. Using Python 2.7.12, OCaml 4.02.3 and Frama-C Silicon, if I copy your code and then add, say, `p.communicate()`, it outputs the result of running WP on the program, without errors. Maybe adding the entire Python script and `file.c` itself could help reproducing it...

Comment: By the way, the warnings about the preprocessor should *not* happen when using a standard gcc. They may be caused by the same issue (e.g., during `configure`, if gcc was not able to run properly, this may have caused Frama-C to believe a custom preprocessor was being used), or something else. In any way, your error message seems more related to OCaml than to Frama-C itself, since all Frama-C is doing here is calling gcc in a fairly standard way.

Comment: @anol, you are right, I don't think that issues is related to Frama-C but probably related to OCaml. And as I mentioned in the question "this error only occur when I start the process(to execute Frama-c) from my application, and not if I start it from a python console".

Comment: I am guessing that my python application sets some env variable or path because of which OCaml process fails with error "No child processes". Unfortunately, the python application is proprietary and I can't share it.
I can execute gcc command `gcc -E -C -I. -dD -D__FRAMAC__ -nostdinc -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc -o '/tmp/2884428408.c2da79b.i' '/home/usr/project/test.c'` sucessfully on my machine.

Comment: And if you try to call gcc directly from your application, or call an OCaml program that simply calls `Sys.command`? If you compiled Frama-C from source, running `make VERBOSEMAKE=y` will print the command-lines used to compile each Frama-C file. That can provide extra details about OCaml compilation flags used by Frama-C, but I'm not sure that will help much.

Comment: I will try to execute gcc and Ocaml program that calls Sys.command from my application and see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Frama-C. However, the error message is coming from somebody's (OCaml's? Python's?) runtime, indicating that a system call failed with the `ECHILD` error. The two system calls that `system()` makes are `fork()` and `waitpid()`. It's the latter system call that can return `ECHILD`. What it means is that there's no child process to wait for. One good possibility is that the `fork()` failed. `fork()` fails when the system is full of processes (unlikely) or when a per-user process limit has been reached. You could check whether you're running up against a limit of this kind.

Another possibility that occurs to me is that some other part of the code is already handling child processes using signal handling (`SIGCHLD`). So the reason there's no child process to wait for is that it has already been handled elsewhere. This gets complicated pretty fast, so I would hope this isn't the problem.